# How can I output the <template /> tag to the DOM in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, web-component, native-web-component

I have a custom library built on Stencil that I need to integrate with Vue, and this library relies on the browser's `<template />` tag.

For example, I need to render the following code to the dom:

```html
<my-custom-list>
  <template>
    <my-custom-title></my-custom-title>
    <my-custom-description></my-custom-description>
  </template>
</my-custom-list>
```

`my-custom-list` will then get whatever is inside the template and use it for each of the items in the list.

I managed to get it to work by using the `v-html` directive, for example:

```
<my-custom-list v-html="<template><my-custom-title></my-custom-title><my-custom-description></my-custom-description></template>">
</my-custom-list>
```

However, I would also like to be able to use Vue components inside this template tag, like:

```html
<my-custom-list>
  <template>
    <my-custom-title></my-custom-title>
    <my-custom-description></my-custom-description>
    <custom-vue-component></custom-vue-component>
  </template>
</my-custom-list>
```

Some old answers online suggest using the `is` directive to be able to output the template tag, like `<div is="template">` but that has been deprecated.

I am not even sure if this is possible, but any insights would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`v-pre`](https://vuejs.org/api/built-in-directives.html#v-pre) directive to skip compilation for parts of your components.

```html
<my-custom-list v-pre>
  <template>
    <my-custom-title></my-custom-title>
    <my-custom-description></my-custom-description>
    <custom-vue-component></custom-vue-component>
  </template>
</my-custom-list>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, unfortunately that doesn't work. I'm not too sure why. But also, that would not allow me to use vue components inside my templates...
I am thinking that the best option is to create new components in my html file using the default template tag and reuse that in the html code that goes in v-html

Comment: Can you try wrapping your template tag in another one and using `v-pre` on that one then? Like`<template v-pre><template><my-custom-title>...</template></template>`

Comment: sorry, I wasn't very clear, I think it works the way you are expecting it - I can see the `<template>` tag, and trying the above I can see the two of them, but that doesn't work with the library I'm trying to implement. Maybe something to do with the rendering order? thanks for the help though! for now I'll stick with the v-html version + defining my components top level so I can use them in the html templates, like 
```js
const resultTextField = defineCustomElement(ResultTextField);
customElements.define('result-text-field', resultTextField);
```